# Algebraic angles of a plane

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Three planes have equations:

- Plane1: $ ax+2y+z=3$
- Plane2: $ x+ay+z=4$
- Plane3: $ x+y+az = 5$

Given that the angle between Plane1 and Plane2 is equal to the angle between Plane2 and Plane3 show that $a$ must satisfy the quartic equation:

$5a^4+2a^3-2a^2-8a-3=0$

So I understand you need to find the normals which are $(a,2,1)$, $(1,a,1)$ and $(1,1,a)$ respectively. I then plugged these into the cosine equation for each respective plane pair  and then got very weird numbers. I think you're meant to make them equal but this doesn't work, so here I am!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT...The angle between the first two planes is given by $$\cos\theta=\frac{\left(\begin{matrix}a\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}1\\a\\1\end{matrix}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+2^2+1^2}\sqrt{1^2+a^2+1^2}}$$
$$=\frac{3a+1}{\sqrt{a^2+5}\sqrt{a^2+2}}$$

In a similar way, the angle between the second two planes is given by $$\cos\theta=\frac{2a+1}{\sqrt{a^2+2}\sqrt{a^2+2}}$$

Set these equal to each other and the result will follow...

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this but I already got those numbers. Its when I tried to simplify them that i ran into problems. Im probably missing something obvious but i'm not sure what. Its good to know I'm on the right track though so I appreciate the response.

Comment: you can cancel one of the square roots and square both sides. The result follows quite easily

Comment: Thanks, I guess I had tried to overcomplicate  it when I was simplifying! I was essentially trying to simplify each fraction before equating them together.

Comment: interesting that if v1 dot v2 and v2dot v3 are equal to each other then they cancel and the equation becomes based only on the square-root part... i wonder if the answer is ever degree 2 instead of degree 4...

Comment: @don bright surely the only thing that cancels is $\sqrt{a^2+2}$?

Comment: what i meant to say is that if we modified the original 3 equations so the dot products v1.v2 and v2.v3 are equal then the numerators of cos(theta) will also be equal, and so the entire thing will be determined by the denominators.